# Nokia Media Query override Apple iPad Tablet

Tags: css, media-queries

I am learning media query . I am trying to give different width for diverse devices from [this](http://mobiletest.me/) web Page . I building 6 media Query (without Samsung Galaxy ,it i will later to do …) , all working OK  but write the Nokia Code , them override the **Hover** from  Apple iPad Tablet .

The Media Query for Apple iPad Mini

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 64em) and (orientation: portrait)  {

  body {
    display: grid;
    background-color: #ebf5d7;
    grid-template-columns: 11% 76% 13%;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 70vh auto;
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-areas:
       "header  header  header"
       "nav     nav     nav"
       "linkBox main    infoBox"
       "footer  footer  footer";
  }
  body > main {
   height: 70vh;
  }
  #name {font-size: 0.55em;}
  #email {font-size: 0.55em;}
  #text {font-size: 0.8em;}
  #comment {font-size: 0.5em;}
  #externalLinks a{text-align: left;}
  #externalLinks ul {margin: 2px;}

  #navs a{font-size: 15px;}
  #externalLinks ul {margin-left: -10px;}
  #externalLinks a  {font-size: 13px}
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     left: 82px;
     top: 205px; 
  }       
}

  /* Tablet iPad 4 generation & iPad air, Landscape */

@media only screen and (min-width: 47.5em) 
               and (max-width: 64em) 
               and (orientation: landscape){
   body {
      display: grid;
      background-color: #ebf5d7;
      grid-template-columns: 8% 77% 15%;
      grid-row-gap: 5px;
      grid-template-areas:
        "header  header  header"
        "nav     nav     nav"
        "linkBox main    infoBox"
        "footer  footer  footer";
      }
      body > header {
        background-image: url("Bilder/view.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 80px;
        margin-bottom: -8px; 
      }
      #navs a{font-size: 15px;}
      #externalLinks ul {margin-left: -10px;}
      #externalLinks a  {font-size: 13px;}
      .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
         left: 78px;
         top: 238px; 
   }                    
}
```

My Nokia Lumia 920 Code;

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 48em) and (orientation :  landscape) {

   body {   
      display: -ms-grid;
      display: grid;
      grid-row-gap: 5px; 
      background-color: #ebf5d7;
      grid-template-columns: 9% 75% 16%;
      grid-template-areas:

        "header   header    header"
        "nav      nav          nav"
        "linkBox  main     infoBox"
        "footer   footer   footer";

    -ms-grid-columns: 9% 75% 16%;
    -ms-grid-row:  120px 80px 103px 200px 110px 90px; 
    -ms-grid-gap: 5px;
  } 
  body > header {
   background-image: url("Bilder/view.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   padding: 60px;
   margin-bottom: 1px; 
  }   
  #navs a{
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  #externalLinks ul {
    margin-left: -12px;
  }
  #externalLinks a  {
    font-size: 10px;
  }        
  #name {font-size: 0.55em;}
  #email {font-size: 0.55em;}
  #text {font-size: 0.3em;}

    /* HOVER  */

  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {

    left: 64px;
    top: 194px; 
  }  
} 

@media only screen and (max-width : 47.5em) and (orientation : portrait) {

   body {   
     display: -ms-grid;
     display: grid;
     grid-row-gap: 5px; 
     background-color: #ebf5d7;
     grid-template-columns: 20% 70% 10%;
     grid-template-areas:

        "header   header    header"
        "nav      nav          nav"
        "linkBox  main     main"
       "footer   footer   footer";
     -ms-grid-columns: 20% 70% 10%;
     -ms-grid-row:  120px 80px 103px 200px 110px 90px; 
     -ms-grid-gap: 5px;
   } 
   body > header {
     background-image: url("Bilder/view.png");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     padding: 55px;
     margin-bottom: 1px; 
   }
   #navs a{font-size: 11px; padding: 0px 6px;}
   #externalLinks ul {margin-left: -12px;}
   #externalLinks a {font-size: 10px;}        
   #name {font-size: 0.55em;}
   #email {font-size: 0.55em;}
   #text {font-size: 0.3em;}

      /* HOVER  */

   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      left: 42px;
      top: 170px; 
   }  
}
```

Because Nokia OS Windows it is , i write `display: -ms-grid;` .

[Here](https://codepen.io/mezb/pen/rPaeaR) all Media Query Code from **tablet_index.css** .

The meta tags;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I using PHP Code to import/include to CSS File ;

```
<style>
<?php 

   include 'CSS/me.css';
   include 'CSS/tablet_index.css';
?>
</style>
```

I am since a Week who to try to Display them... , can please anyone help me to solve this Problem , very Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my Problem...

**First** , the Media Parameter from my Portrait in Nokia , i wrote

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 47.5em) and (orientation : portrait) {
```

When i should to write..

```
 @media only screen and (max-width : 460px) and (orientation : portrait) {
```

how the parameter they [give](http://mobiletest.me/nokia_lumia_920_emulator) ... **Css resolution 460x768** .

In **Nokia** and **Apple iPad mini** his width start Parametar  is 768px...

**Second** , because i  gave **Hover** Parameter without Layout  to my Nokia ,  it override ..

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  left: 42px;
  top: 170px; 
}
```

now give it to my Nokia..

```
 body > #externalLinks .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
  left: 55px;
  top: 145px; 
}
```